# How Can I write and display a description of my Drupal view?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

The structure of a Drupal views is in the following manner:

- View Title
- View Content

How and where can I write and display a description for my view, above the content:

- View Title
- View Description
- View Content

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your view settings find **HEADER** in the middle column under **BLOCK SETTINGS**, click add select ***Global: Text area***. The provide your text and title if you wish.